# Pivot table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a pivot table for **Count_Orders** as well as **Count_Sessions**. However, with the current code I can only do the calculation for **Count_Orders** once I am trying to add **Count_Sessions" I get the following error:

`SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`

Main table

```
Month      Country  Count_Orders Count_Sessions
2019-01    UK       100           40
2019-01    US       230           60
```

Desired Output table

```
Month      US_Orders  US_Sessions  UK_Orders US_Sessions Share_Orders Share_Sessions
2019-01    100        230          40        60          0.43          0.66
```

My current code:

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(appended_df, index=['Month'], columns='Country', values='Count_Orders') #Pivoting on required columns
df_flattened = pd.DataFrame(df_pivot.to_records()) #Flatten the pivot table to get a datafrmae
df_flattened['Share'] = df_flattened['UK']/df_flattened['US'] #Creating the ratio column
```

Comment: FYI: when I am adding "Count_Sessions" to values I get the above error

Comment: Do you mean `pd.pivot(df, index='Month', columns='Country')`?

Comment: no so ideally I would want to add "values = 'Count_Orders','Count_Sessions'

Comment: @user12625679, can you check your expected output is correct. Can you explain how  `US_Sessions, US_Sessions, UK_Orders, US_Sessions`  column values arrived. Where `US_Sessions` comes two times and value `230` how it comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
res = pd.pivot_table(df, index="Month", columns=["Country"])

res.columns = [c[0] + "_" + c[1] for c in res.columns]
res[["orders_ratio", "sessions_ratio"]] = res.iloc[:, [0,2]].divide(res.iloc[:, [1,3]].values)
```

The output is:

[image]